# Spoofing an API with SinonJS?

Tags: javascript

When developing an API (in my case an API that wraps around a websockets service), is there a good way of giving it's skeletal implementation to another developer so that he can work independent of me? If my API is still in the design phase for example, I'm thinking that I could give an outline of the methods that will be available and all the possible return types.

I realise that I could just give him a dummy object with all the methods inside but it would be great if that dummy object could be tied in with his unit tests and so on.

I've been looking at [SinonJs][1]: http://sinonjs.org/ and in particular at the Stub functionality it provides. However I am not sure if what I've outlined here is an appropriate use of stubs.

Any advice appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I guess this question should of been:

'How to write unit tests using Jasmine, Sinon and a mock API'

It was a bit of a silly question because it turns out that Sinon actually has it's own 'fake server' which is very easy to use. In ignorance of this my first idea was to mock or spy on XHR stuff.

The code I ended up with is here: https://gist.github.com/james-gardner/11405316

See 'DummyViewSpec.js' for examples of the fake server stuff. Edits welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about an easy way to have a web app (or other REST) API up and running - http://flatironjs.org/ might be a good option for you. It's full JS stack both on the server (node.js) and client. However, you can do an API mockups with any other routing library (search npm - there are A LOT of them).
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool to mockup the whole APIs using schema and random data with types
https://github.com/homerquan/kakuen

I created and used it to inject dependance of api